# Overriding an abstract method while using the method

Tags: scala, overriding

I want to do something like this

```
abstract class Foo {

    def bar:String
    def modifiedFoo:Foo = new Foo(){
        override def bar = super.bar+"\n"
    }
}
```

but this is not legitimate ("method bar in class Foo is accessed from super,
it may not be abstract unless it is overriden by a member declared abstract 
and override" which inturn is only legal for Traits).

I could move the method modifiedFoo
into the companion object with signature modifiedFoo(foo:Foo) but this is
less elegant.
How do you handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use `self` in the following way:

```
abstract class Foo {

  self: Foo =>

  def bar: String

  def modifiedFoo: Foo = new Foo() {
    override def bar = self.bar + "\n"
  }

}
```